# How to name a file while uploading via file uploader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I have a file uploaded in asp.net webforms and it works but i want to append name with each file i upload like when I choose file from disk then i should also be able to give it a name.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

.cs

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {


                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/BPA/") + fileName);
                HdnFieldFard.Value = fileName;




            }
```

Comment: Instead of `fileName`, you can use any name. What's problem with this?

Comment: I mean a user defined name, i.e. you click UPLOAD FILE control, it goes to C drive u choose file and then give it name 'myimage01.jpg' and then click open

Comment: Currently I see that its uploaded within `SiteImages/BPA/` folder. So you can give any name like `FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/BPA/") + "anyname");`

Comment: You can use `Path.GetExtension` at the end of name, so it preserves file extension.

Comment: but this kind of name would remain same for every file

Comment: or kinda same , it doesn't give the user an authority to write his own name

Comment: So you can create something like your ownname, like `Dim fileName As String = "MyFile_" & Format(DateTime.Now, "MMddyyyyhhmmss")`

Comment: still it doesn't give authority to user to write own name in case of multiple files

Comment: Oh you mean, you want to allow users to give their own names while uploading file? In that case you need to give them ability to write name in textbox.

Comment: but that still would be a problem while uploading multiple attachments

Answer (score 0):

Change fileName to whatever you like..

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

EDIT: Preferably use your chosen filename + use Path.GetExtension to keep the extension of the uploaded file.

Comment: I mean a user defined name, i.e. you click UPLOAD FILE control, it goes to C drive u choose file and then give it name 'myimage01.jpg' and then click open